# Mapping . with hostname VC++

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++

I have an application which has some services. Currently these services are configured with the IP address/hostname of the machine where it is installed and so the services bind to that IP.

So customers have to configure the host name/IP address. Now the requirement is that the customer should only configure local or '.' just like SQL and the services should pick up the local host name or IP and still function.

Which is the easiest way to achieve this in VC++?

Comment: doesn't localhost/127.0.0.1 help?

Answer (score 0):

If the service shall only be accessible from the computer itself, then use IP address 127.0.0.1 or DNS name localhost. If the service shall be accessible from any network computer then bind to IP address 0.0.0.0. This will bind to every network adapter installed - take care if this is not desired in a scenario where a user is connected to two networks and the service shall only be available on the trusted network. Of course the service can bind to 0.0.0.0 and let the firewall do the blocking on a second network, if necessary.